# Ember-CLI Resolver: Naming Convention Questions

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I am brand new to ember... working through the ember guides AND trying to apply that same knowledge through the ember-cli guides simultaneously.

I am noticing there there are a few big gaps in logic between the two when it comes to the ES6 Resolver and it is causing problems for me, particularly when i want to reference things like ApplicationRoute, ApplicationController, and the like.

I have to ask, for my own sanity,  how to I define an ApplicationRoute or an ApplicationController?  Are they saved as application.js or index.js?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ApplicationRoute would be saved under `app/routes/application.js`, ApplicationController would be saved as `app/controllers/application.js`.

as long as those files `export default` the proper subclassed Route or Controller, respectively, everything should be fine.

Comment: ok good thanks... i was confused because in a nested directory i need to do something like `app/routes/accounts/index.js` and `app/controllers/accounts/index.js`.. that is correct in this case, yes?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Although I must admit, I've never done that because I prefer seeing more relevant file names in my IDE.